# Format numbers to two decimal places with KVC?

Tags: formatting, numerical, kvc

The code below connects a slider output to a label in a window. The connection works. But, I have not been able to format the numerical display. For example I'd like to display only two decimals. I can't find an example anywhere. Thanks

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface appController : NSObject{
float foo;
}
@property float foo;

@end

#import "appController.h"
@implementation appController
@synthesize foo;
-(id)init{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 50.00] forKey:@"foo"];
}
return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Do not confuse a number with a string presentation of a number.